# Using generate to fill list in template class c++

Tags: c++, templates, generate

I am working on a project where i have a template class in which i have a  List. This function i have included is meant to fill the list with random numbers. But each time i run it it says that "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments" and what i have understood is that i cant use a function that returns a value in Generate.

How do i make Generator and Random to functors? Is there a way to do this without it?

```
template<typename T>
void ListManipulator<T>::fillList()
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> random(1000, 2000);
    std::default_random_engine generator(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0)));

    std::generate(theList.begin(), theList.end(), random(generator));
```

Comment: Algorithms are cool and all but `for(auto& e : theList) e = random(generator);` is just as long and just as easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> random(1000, 2000);
std::default_random_engine generator(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0)));

std::generate(theList.begin(), theList.end(), 
    [&random, &generator]{ return random(generator); });
```

[`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) requires a generator which is a function with a signature:

```
Ret fun();
```

And you provide not a function at all, but a `double` value.